# Clear contents of dropdown menu on click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hello and thanks for looking. I am very new to javascript/jQuery. I have a button that calls a function called SelectOptions():

[image]

Here is the code for the function when the button is pressed:

```
    function SelectOptions() {
        var selectedLJP ='';
        var selectedFrmn = '';
        if (assLocJobPh.length == 1 && assForeman.length == 1) {
            selectedLJP = assLocJobPh[0].value;
            selectedFrmn = assForeman[0].value;
        } else {
            selectedLJP = $('#DTCOption').find('[id*=ddlLocJobPhOpt]').val();
            selectedFrmn = $('#DTCOption').find('[id*=ddlFrmnOpt]').val();
            $('#OptionFormContainer').popup('close');

        }
        dailyTCOptions.loggedUser = loggedAppUser;
        dailyTCOptions.locationJobPhase = selectedLJP;
        dailyTCOptions.foreman = selectedFrmn;
        dailyTCOptions.Badges = [];
        LoadDTCOptionPage();
    }
```

Here is the HTML/server controls:

```
                <form name="OptionForm" method="post">
                    <p>
                        <label for="ddlLocJobPhOpt" class="ui-accessible">Location Job Phase</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlLocJobPhOpt" data-mini="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="ddlFrmnOpt" class="ui-accessible">Foreman</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlFrmnOpt" data-mini="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </p>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelectOptions" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" runat="server" data-role="button" Class="custom-btn" data-inline="true" data-theme="c" data-transition="pop" UseSubmitBahavior="false" href="#" data-mini="true" OnClientClick="SelectOptions()">GO</asp:LinkButton>
                </form>
```

Currently, when go is selected and a person navigates back to this popup, the location job phase selection goes back to default but foreman, which is populated after the first drop down is selected stays at whatever the previous value was.

My goal is to reset the first dropdown menu to the default (Select) and clear the second drop down as shown above. THis is the code I added to the end of the click event function:

```
        selectedLJP.val("0");
        selectedFrmn.empty();
```

However, the second dropbox is staying populated when I go navigate back to it. How do I clear the drop down menu on button click?

Comment: You are looking to cleare it on client-side or on PostBack when you click Go?

Comment: Client-side, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Try something like `selectedFrmn.find('option').remove();` to remove the `<option>`s located inside the `<select>` you want to clear.

Comment: Thanks, VIDesignz. Looking at the dev tools in chrome it does look like the dropdown list consists of <option> tags but the code you gave me is still not removing them.